# Determine the mapping matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

A $3$-dimensional vector space $V$ with basis $v = (v_1,v_2,v_3)$ is given. Furthermore a linear map: $f\colon V \to \mathbb R^3$ is given by:

$$f(v_1) = (4,0,-2), f(v_2) = (-2, 0, 1), f(v_3) = (2,1,-1)$$

Determine the mapping matrix for $f$ with respect to the basis $v$ of $V$, and find the image vector for $17v_1 - 15v_2 + 16v_3$

Find to proper vectors that belong to $\ker(f)$

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Welcome to MSC. Please use MathJax . See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: In what basis are those image vectors expressed?

Comment: I suppose its on the standard e basis, but im not pretty sure, I mean the question its just that, I didnt change anything .

Comment: The matrix has to output $v$-basis vectors, so the only possibility that will allow you to solve this problem is if those coordinate vectors are expressed relative to the $v$-basis.